# How to use CSS variables in SASS [scale-color] function?

Tags: css, variables, sass, colors, css-selectors

Similar question but need this help, I want to change the overall website color using two css variables, `--color-primary` and `--color-secondary`, because I have two color option in the admin dashboard. Admin can change the color for every listed company according to their branding.

So I have 5 colors, Two are dark and other three are light from same color family.

I want to convert the dark to lighten color in some places. Here is my code which is not working.
[Codepen](https://codepen.io/figarali/pen/wvqWmQO)

```
:root {
--color-primary: blue;
--color-secondary: red;
}

$primary : var(--color-primary);

//convert to light form primary color
$bg-color : scale-color($primary, $lightness:80%);

.logo{
  background: $bg-color;
  height: 100px;
  width:100px;
}
```

Does anybody know how can I fix this issue? Or is it just not possible? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It cannot take the variable that assigned from css root selecter as an argument. But you can do this as folows:

```
$primary:blue;
$bg-color:lighten($primary,80%);
or $bg-color:scale-color($primary,$lightness:80%);
.logo{
    background: $bg-color;
}
```

<////EDITED///>
This web site may has a solution
https://codyhouse.co/blog/post/how-to-combine-sass-color-functions-and-css-variables

Comment: Thanks, But I need CSS variable, because I want to change the color scheme on runtime, system can't compile the SCSS on live server. Or if you have any idea about how to compile SCSS on live server Please let me know.

Answer (score -6):

Remove the primary color and you will get going

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer! It would be nice if you could improve your answer a bit with a bit more explanation. Perhaps showing some code for example.